# Size and position an image in a Powerpoint 2013 Template

Tags: image, templates, resize, powerpoint

I've been asked to create a template for PowerPoint 2013 and have most of it working.

However, I need to include the company logo and I need to be able to make the template in such a way that the user can change the slide size (switch from a 16:9 screen to 4:3)

If I include the logo when designing the template at 16:9, then resize the slide size to 4:3 the logo gets squished. Alternatively, if I design at 4:3 and switch to 16:9, the logo gets stretched.

Is it possible to add the logo to the template, and prevent it from being altered when the slide size changes? If it is, please can someone let me know how this is done? I've looked at the options and cant see anything and a Google search has turned up nothing but "how to create a template".

I'd rather not make the user to have to add the logo to each slide.

Comment: Do-not use the `logo` tag for your logos .. It is a programming language

Comment: This is more a question for SuperUser than StackOverflow, but a couple suggestions: - Give the user two templates, one for each aspect ratio or;  -  Teach users to use PPT's Page Setup feature to change from one aspect ratio to another (it won't distort shapes) or;  - do some research on SuperThemes. I don't know much about them, other than that they allow for multiple aspect ratios and switching from one to another w/o distortion

Comment: Sorry I never replied sooner. Thanks for your comments!